# Django: ImportError: No module named social.apps.django_app

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I had an application that I created in Windows 7, and it worked perfectly. A few days back, I migrated to Ubuntu and copied the project file in Ubuntu. Now, when I try running the project using `python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named social.apps.django_app
```

What seems to be wrong here? I'm new to Ubuntu, so any help would be appreciated. I have the same version of Python and Django installed in Ubuntu that I had in Windows as well.

Comment: Did you install `python-social-auth`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you need to install a module on your ubuntu machine that already exists on your windows 7 environment.  If you have pip installed, try this on Windows & Ubuntu, and look for missing packages

```
pip freeze
```

You will see something on your windows environment that is missing on Ubuntu, like python-social-auth -- your fix will be do something like on Ubuntu:

```
pip install python-social-auth
```

or

```
sudo pip install python-social-auth
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I completely forgot to install `python-social-auth` module in Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you use virtual environment for your project? if so, be sure that you have activated it before installing your project dependencies, use `pip freeze` inside your virtual env. to see the installed packages, if you do not use it, simple `pip install python-social-auth` should normaly resolve your problem.

For me, I can see the following list of installed packages inside my virtual environment (using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6):

```
(venv)root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/test-auth# pip install python-social-auth
(venv)root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/test-auth# pip freeze
PyJWT==1.4.0
argparse==1.2.1
oauthlib==1.0.1
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.12
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

[`social-auth-app-django`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) is the one that should be used since [they reorganized the code base](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth#deprecation-notice---2016-12-03).